# Nextflow: How to process multiple samples

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

I have few `fq.gz` files for few samples. I am trying to process all samples at once using `nextflow`. But somehow, I am unable to process all the samples at once . But I can process a single sample at once. Here is the data structure and my code for processing single sample.

[image]

My nextflow code

```
params.sampleName="sample1"
params.fastq_path = "data/${params.sampleName}/*{1,2}.fq.gz"

fastq_files = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.fastq_path)

params.ref = "ab.fa"
ref = file(params.ref)

process foo {
    input:
    set pairId, file(reads) from fastq_files

    output:

    file("${pairId}.bam") into bamFiles_ch

    script:
    """
    echo ${reads[0].toRealPath().getParent().baseName}
    bwa-mem2 mem -t 8 ${ref} ${reads[0].toRealPath()} ${reads[1].toRealPath()} | samtools sort -@8 -o ${pairId}.bam
    samtools index -@8 ${pairId}.bam
    """
}

process samToolsMerge {
    publishDir "./aligned_minimap/", mode: 'copy', overwrite: 'false'

    input:
    file bamFile from bamFiles_ch.collect()

    output:
    file("**")

    script:
    """
    samtools merge ${params.sampleName}.bam ${bamFile}
    samtools index -@ 8 ${params.sampleName}.bam
    """
}
```

So need help to solve. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've already built in a way to set your target sample name using:

```
params.sampleName="sample1"
params.fastq_path = "data/${params.sampleName}/*{1,2}.fq.gz"
```

To have the glob pattern match *all* samples, you could simply set the wildcard on the command line using:

```
nextflow run main.nf --sampleName '*'
```

Note the quotation marks above. If these are ignored, the glob star will be expanded by your shell before it is passed to your Nextflow command.

---

---

The short answer is that you need some easy way to extract the sample name from the parent directory. Then you need some way to group the coordinate-sorted BAMs by the sample name. Below, I've used the new Nextflow [DSL 2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html) but it's not strictly necessary. I just find the new DSL 2 code a lot easier to read and debug. Below is just an example, and you'll need to adapt it to suit your exact use case, but that said, it should do very similar things. It uses a special [groupKey](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v21.04.3/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/extension/GroupKey.groovy) so that we can dynamically specify the expected number of elements in each tuple prior to calling the [groupTuple](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) operator. This lets us stream the collected values as soon as possible so that each sample can 'merge' when all of it's readgroups have been aligned. Without this, all input readgroups would need to finish alignment before the merge could begin.

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
process {

  shell = [ '/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail' ]
}
```

Contents of `main.nf`:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.ref_fasta = "GRCh38.primary_assembly.genome.chr22.fa.gz"
params.fastq_files = "data/*/*.read{1,2}.fastq.gz"


process bwa_index {

    conda 'bwa-mem2'

    input:
    path fasta

    output:
    path "${fasta}.{0123,amb,ann,bwt.2bit.64,pac}"

    """
    bwa-mem2 index "${fasta}"
    """
}


process bwa_mem2 {

    tag { [sample, readgroup].join(':') }

    conda 'bwa-mem2 samtools'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), val(readgroup), path(reads)
    path bwa_index

    output:
    tuple val(sample), val(readgroup), path("${readgroup}.bam{,.bai}")

    script:
    def idxbase = bwa_index.first().baseName
    def out_files = [ "${readgroup}.bam", "${readgroup}.bam.bai" ].join('##idx##')
    def (r1, r2) = reads

    """
    bwa-mem2 mem \\
        -R '@RG\\tID:${readgroup}\\tSM:${sample}' \\
        -t ${task.cpus} \\
        "${idxbase}" \\
        "${r1}" \\
        "${r2}" |
    samtools sort \\
        --write-index \\
        -@ ${task.cpus} \\
        -o "${out_files}"
    """
}


process samtools_merge {

    tag { sample }

    conda 'samtools'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(indexed_bam_files)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}.bam{,.bai}")

    script:
    def out_files = [ "${sample}.bam", "${sample}.bam.bai" ].join('##idx##')
    def input_bam_files = indexed_bam_files
        .findAll { it.name.endsWith('.bam') }
        .collect { /"${it}"/ }
        .join(' \\\n'+' '*8)

    """
    samtools merge \\
        --write-index \\
        -o "${out_files}" \\
        ${input_bam_files}
    """
}


workflow {

    ref_fasta = file( params.ref_fasta )
    bwa_index( ref_fasta )

    Channel.fromFilePairs( params.fastq_files ) \
        | map { readgroup, reads ->
            def (sample_name) = reads*.parent.baseName as Set

            tuple( sample_name, readgroup, reads )
        } \
        | groupTuple() \
        | map { sample, readgroups, reads ->
            tuple( groupKey(sample, readgroups.size()), readgroups, reads )
        } \
        | transpose() \
        | set { sample_readgroups }

    bwa_mem2( sample_readgroups, bwa_index.out )

    sample_readgroups \
        | join( bwa_mem2.out, by: [0,1] ) \
        | map { sample_key, readgroup, reads, indexed_bam ->
            tuple( sample_key, indexed_bam )
        } \
        | groupTuple() \
        | map { sample_key, indexed_bam_files ->
            tuple( sample_key.toString(), indexed_bam_files.flatten() )
        } \
        | samtools_merge
}
```

Run Like:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false main.nf
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `main.nf` [zen_gautier] - revision: dcde9efc8a
Creating Conda env: bwa-mem2 [cache /home/steve/working/stackoverflow/69702077/work/conda/env-8cc153b2eb20a5374bf435019a61c21a]
[63/73c96b] Submitted process > bwa_index
Creating Conda env: bwa-mem2 samtools [cache /home/steve/working/stackoverflow/69702077/work/conda/env-5c358e413a5318c53a45382790eecbd4]
[52/6a92d3] Submitted process > bwa_mem2 (HBR:HBR_Rep2_ERCC-Mix2_Build37-ErccTranscripts-chr22)
[8b/535b21] Submitted process > bwa_mem2 (UHR:UHR_Rep3_ERCC-Mix1_Build37-ErccTranscripts-chr22)
[dc/03d949] Submitted process > bwa_mem2 (UHR:UHR_Rep1_ERCC-Mix1_Build37-ErccTranscripts-chr22)
[e4/bfd08b] Submitted process > bwa_mem2 (HBR:HBR_Rep1_ERCC-Mix2_Build37-ErccTranscripts-chr22)
[d5/e2aa27] Submitted process > bwa_mem2 (UHR:UHR_Rep2_ERCC-Mix1_Build37-ErccTranscripts-chr22)
[c2/23ce8a] Submitted process > bwa_mem2 (HBR:HBR_Rep3_ERCC-Mix2_Build37-ErccTranscripts-chr22)
Creating Conda env: samtools [cache /home/steve/working/stackoverflow/69702077/work/conda/env-912cee20caec78e112a5718bb0c00e1c]
[28/006c03] Submitted process > samtools_merge (HBR)
[3b/51311c] Submitted process > samtools_merge (UHR)
```

Comment: How about the `bamFiles_ch.collect()`? Will it collect data samples for each sample or all at once.
if its all at once, than its a problem.

Comment: @ArijitPanda that will collect all items in the channel (i.e. all at once). I see now what you're trying to do here. I'll update my answer soon...

Comment: @ArijitPanda Please see the update above and let me know if anything is unclear. Cheers.

Comment: Great help for a nextflow beginner like me! However, I'd like to cover two additional issues on which I got stuck:
(1) samtools sort --write-index ... will emit .csi index file instead of .bai by default. At least newer version like 1.12. So this "##idx##*.bai" is compulsory. 
(2) [RG tag] While my PG from bwa-mem2 had 2 ID attributes samtools merge did not emit any error. It was quite troublesome as both awk and Groovy converts \t to the tab. The workaround is to omit \t in awk command by splitting it in a few variables and escape it with \\t in Groovy.

Comment: @Krzysztof Glad you found it useful. As you discovered, newer samtools includes a `--write-index` option which will produce a CSI index. I included a line of code to show how to produce a BAI. But you may just prefer to use `samtools index <bam>` instead which has a longer pedigree and would be compatible with most (if not all) versions of samtools. I updated the code above to include a line to show how I add the `@RG` tag. The trick is the same though, to escape the backslash with `\\t`.